# the file %CommonDir%\publish.tlb could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Every time I install and try to launch Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I get the following popup with the following message:

> the file %CommonDir%\publish.tlb could not be loaded. An attempt to repair this condition failed because the file could not be found. Please re-install the program.

I have tried re-installing it a number of times but I still the message above. I have researching it but I can't seem to find anything. Does anyone have an idea, how this issue could be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please run this command from the command prompt by typing windows+R key:

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

The problem should get fixed.

Comment: This also seems to fix my error: `%commondir%\dte80.olb could not be loaded`

Comment: This works, and is a much better suggestion than what Microsoft provides on the pop-up window itself. Thanks!