# Series of %commondir%\* could not be loaded from Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7, registry

*Already tried the [fix here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093112/the-file-commondir-publish-tlb-could-not-be-loaded), no avail.*

I get a series of messages like this upon launching Community 2015

> The file %CommonDir%\{$file} could not be loaded. An attempt to repair this condition failed because the file could not be found.
>
> Please reinstall this program

This happened after I attempted to go to Windows 10, gave up on it, and rolled back to my old Win7 image.

Additionally, I have a unique setup. I have an SSD w/ my Windows install on it and all my Program Files are on my secondary drive. I used the registry hack (the one not recommended by MS) to change all %ProgramFiles% locations to my secondary drive. I have since just moved everything off my C:\ drive and made directory junctions from C:\ to my secondary drive. As well as reinstalling several times, none of this has worked.

If there is a fix to my directory structures or a way to simply remove VS so I can reinstall Windows and try this over, I would appreciate it. So far, I have not found a way to remove VS.

Comment: Getting the same after update 3.